# Create local functions in F#

Tags: c#, .net, f#, functional-programming

For example, I have 2 additive functions:

```
module Add

let add2 a =
    let innerFn a = a + 2
    innerFn a
let add2' a =
    let innerFn' () = a + 2
    innerFn' ()

let res1 = add2 0
let res2 = add2' 1
```

From what I known, both `innerFn`s will be compiled to `FSharpFunc<int,int>` and `FSharpFunc<unit,int>` respectively, and will be initialized everytime the `add2` or `add2'` is called.

How can I rewrite the code to transform them to static local functions of the static class (thus no FSharpFunc initialization), like in C# 7?

Comment: You say that the inner functions become *delegates* which you don't want, presumably due to the extra allocations. Huh, I didn't know that and it's not that nice. The important point of C# 7 local methods at the language level is that they *are* local methods, not Func<T> or Action delegates. The optimization is a (very important, very welcome) bonus. Do you really care about delegate allocations that much?

Comment: I see the delegate generation in this case only for Debug builds. A Release build inlines the inner functions, resulting in *no* allocations or calls

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably don't have to worry about this. In a Debug build, every local function becomes a delegate. In a Release build, the functions are either inlined or *do* become static methods in the static class.

By building and decompiling the question's code in a Debug build, you get :

```
public static int add2(int a)
{
    return 5 + (new Program.innerFn@5()).Invoke(a);
}

public static int add2'(int a)
{
    return (new Program.innerFn'@8(a)).Invoke(null);
}
```

Which does show a delegate initialization each time.

In Release though, this becomes :

```
public static int add2(int a)
{
    return a + 2;
}

public static int add2'(int a)
{
    return a + 2;
}
```

The functions were inlined and no delegate was generated.

To avoid indlining, I made `add2` a bit more complex :

```
let add2 a =
    let innerFn a = if a < 3 then a+1 else a + 2
    5 + innerFn a
let add2' a =
    let innerFn' () = a + 2
    innerFn' ()
```

In this case, the Release build generated a static method in the class :

```
public static int add2(int a)
{
    return 5 + Program.innerFn@5(a);
}

public static int add2'(int a)
{
    return a + 2;
}

internal static int innerFn@5(int a)
{
    if (a < 3)
    {
        return a + 1;
    }
    return a + 2;
}
```